# Triangle's inequality of a norm is equivalent to the convexity of the closed unit ball.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove that triangle's inequality in the definition of a norm is equivalent to the convexity of the closed unit ball.

(I proved triangle inequality implies convexity, but I could not prove converse. For converse I tried like this: I took any $x$, $y$ in the normed space $X$, then I derived two new unit vectors $x/||x||$, $y/||y||$ so that the new vectors lie in the closed unit ball and so I can use the convexity of the ball for the vectors $x$ & $y$. But further I could not get the result this way.)

Comment: Do you have any attempts to share? Perhaps what you have tried, you could post what you know and people will be able to help you from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triangle's inequality in the definition of a norm is as follows:

> $$\forall x,y\in X,\ \|x+y\|\le \|x\|+\|y\| $$

Now, the above inequality follows the convexity of the unit closed ball. Let $\lambda\in [0,1]$ and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{B}[0,1]\implies \|\mathbf{x}\|\le 1 $ and $\|\mathbf{y}\|\le 1$. Now consider, 
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda \mathbf{x}+(1-\lambda) \mathbf{y}\| & \le \|\lambda \mathbf{x}\|+\|(1-\lambda)\mathbf{y}\|\\
                            & = \lambda \|\mathbf{x}\|+(1-\lambda)\|\mathbf{y}\|\\
                            & \le \lambda + (1-\lambda)=1
\end{align*} 
Hence, $ \lambda \mathbf{x}+(1-\lambda) \mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{B}[0,1]. $

For the converse see, 
$$ \frac{\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|}=\frac{\|\mathbf{x}\|}{\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|}\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}+\frac{\|\mathbf{y}\|}{\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|}\frac{\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{y}\|}\in \mathbb{B}[0,1] \implies \|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\le \|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$$